# Gesture won't fire if UIButton is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a large button that swiping up and down on it fires some methods using simple gestures. 
A single tap on it fires up `TouchUpInside` event with `largestButtonSingleTap`.
My problem is if I tap the largeButton and keep it pressed, then after a second swiping up the swiping gesture won't work. Trying to figure out why.
I have a few other events on that button such as DragInside , TouchDown , DragExit , TouchCancel. I cancelled all of them  and stayed with an empty method (commented out everything inside largestButtonSingleTap) but still, if the button is pressed > small pause > swipeUp > won't fire. 
Thanks

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upRecognizer;
upRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeUp:)];
[upRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
[_largestButton addGestureRecognizer:upRecognizer];
```

---

```
    - (IBAction)largestButtonSingleTap:(UIButton *)sender
    { //some more code here

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^() {
    ...
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    ...

}
```

### -

**EDIT:**
After reading the answers suggested here I've started a new project thinking that there's something wrong with my code but it still doesn't work. Here is the new project  http://pastebin.com/yz7NaqUD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UISwipeGestureRecognizer is Discrete Gestures, so you can not do that.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html

Touchdown can go with other Continuous Gesture like Pan, pinch, rotation.

Try another way,subclass UIButton and implement touchesMove.

Refer:[iOS Custom gesture recognizer measure length of longpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669212/ios-custom-gesture-recognizer-measure-length-of-longpress)

Comment: You gave me a good hint. I used the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506584/how-do-you-get-the-touchesbegan-coordinates-when-a-uibutton-is-triggered with UITouch as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

the animation block may be blocking user interaction. Try using the allowUserInteraction animation option in your largestButtonSingleTap: method.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    //
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //
}];
```

Comment: I can see the animation is finished when I wait with the button pressed. just then I swipe up. I tried it anyway but it didn't helped.

Comment: hmm try setting a delegate for your gesture recognizer (I posted another answer)

Comment: 've started a new project thinking that there's something wrong with my code but it still doesn't work. Here is the new project http://pastebin.com/yz7NaqUD

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the delegate to your gesture recognizer and implementing:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question with some more info. I tried delegating like this: .h file: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` .m file:`upRecognizer.delegate = self;` still no go.